# What's the purpose of "<<<"?

Tags: shell

I wanted to apply [an answer about non interactive postfix installation on debian distros](https://serverfault.com/a/144010/342516). But I don't get the meaning of the `<<<` operator found in it, that's the first time I see it :

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com"
```

What's its purpose?

When I try it I get a `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *here-string*, not all shells use this syntax, but at least [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh), [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)

Check :

```
man bash | less +/'Here Strings'
```

:

> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> [n]<<
>
> The  word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,
>   and quote removal.  Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed.  The result is supplied as a  single  string,  with  a
>   newline appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).

It's like a *here-doc* but instead of lines, we have just a string

Your error means that you are using the posix shell [sh](/questions/tagged/sh), and *here-string* is not supported.

To fix this, use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or use a *pipe* like this :

```
echo 'string' | command
```